# Why Hibernate Search is not giving newly inserted records?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm new to hibernate Lucene search. In my application, I have some old data I know hibernate Lucene is not aware of transactions. So for that old data, I have created the index manually so it is working like a charm but it is not giving results for newly inserted/updated records. But if I am again doing manual indexing at the time those records are coming. I think records which are inserted/updated via hibernate ORM index will be updated automatically am I right??. If Yes means here why it is not coming.Please assist me some suggestions.

This is my snippet

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

My search code:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] { "skills.skill","role" },
                new StandardAnalyzer());
parser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.OR);
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = null;
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Student.class).get();
BooleanQuery boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();    
boolQuery.add(qb.keyword().onField("vstatus").matching(1).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
boolQuery.add(qb.range().onField("percentage").from(80).to(100).createQuery(),
                BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
FullTextQuery createFullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(boolQuery, Student.class);
        createFullTextQuery.setProjection("studentId", "firstName","lastName","personal.city",);

return createFullTextQuery.list();
```

The Following are my Mapping entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@Component
@Indexed(index="student")
public class Student        
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="student_id")
    private long studentId;     


    @Column(name="first_name")
    @Field(store=Store.YES)
    private String firstName;


    @Column(name="last_name")
    @Field(store=Store.YES)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="visibility_status",columnDefinition="TINYINT")
    @Field(analyze=Analyze.YES,index=Index.YES)
    private int vstatus;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="student",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private ProfileSummary profileSummary;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="student",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private PersonalInfo personal;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<StudentSkills> StudentSkills = new ArrayList<StudentSkills>();

    //setters & getters
}
========================

@Entity
@Table(name="profile_summary")
@Indexed(index="ProfileSummary")
@AnalyzerDef(name = "summaryAnalyzer",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
})
public class ProfileSummary implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4672310608280406464L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="profile_summary_id")
    private long ProfileSummaryId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="student_student_id")
    private Student student


    @Column(name="profile_percentage")
    @Analyzer(definition = "summaryAnalyzer")
    @Field(index=Index.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private int percentage ;        

}

@Entity
@Table(name="student_skills")
public class StudentSkills 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="student_skill_id")
    private long studentSkillId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="student_student_id")
    private Student student

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="skills_skill_id")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Skills skills;

}
```

Similary I added indexing for skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same kind of problem.I think this also one of the reason.It will depends on saving the entity.If you are saving main entity in your case i.e **Student.class**@IndexedEmbedded enough.Where as if you are performing Hibernate Operations on child means you have to  establish bi-directional relationship by using @IndexedEmbedded and @ContainedIn.I think you missed @ContainedIn on other side of the relationship that's why indexes are not updating.

In Profile Summary Entity and as well as on StudentSkill Entity:

```
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="student_student_id")
  @ContainedIn
  private Student student
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `hibernate.search.indexing_strategy` configuration property. If it's set to `manual`, it means you disabled automatic indexing. You should set this to `event`.
2. Check your logs. In some cases, there may be asynchronous errors while indexing, which would not make your transactions fail but would still fail to index your entities.
3. Check your query. When changing the parameters, does it match your mass-indexed entities?
4. If none of the above solves the issue, tell us how exactly you add/update you entities (the code that deals with `EntityManager`/`Session`), and how you manage your transactions (Hibernate Search usually triggers indexing when your transaction is committed)

Comment: 1.I haven't mentioned any property related to indexing_strategy. 2.And there is no transaction related errors.Actually what is my problem is, in the above snippet main entity is Student.class,similarly I have one more entity called DummyStudent.class with same kind of relationship .I am using DummyStudent.class for initial data and Student.class is actual data which is coming though my spring application.For storing Dummy data I created a separate GUI which will persist through Hibernate session.DummyStudent.class is working in both cases.But same thing is not working w.r.t Student